# Can a task still run if App is hanging?

Tags: c#, task

Can a task still run if an application is in an APPHANG state? On the UI thread, the application is hanging (this is by design as I have forced it for testing how to rectify the issue). I understand that it is not at all good practice to have an application in an apphang state but for testing purposes I'd like to know if other tasks can still run seeing how they are not on the main UI thread.

Or does every task go into a locked state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a task still run if an application is in an APPHANG state?

That depends entirely on the specific task.  Some tasks will require the use of the UI thread, based on how they were defined, and some won't.

Perhaps the task is scheduled using a `TaskScheduler` or `SynchronizationContext` that intends to marshal the execution of code to the UI thread.  Perhaps it will only be completed when some other code running on the UI thread triggers an event.  Perhaps it is a continuation of some other task that is in some way dependent on the UI thread.  Perhaps it is running code that, through some form of alternate mechanism is dependent on running code in the UI thread.  There are literally an infinite number of possible ways, through any number of levels of indirection, for a task to not complete if the UI thread is blocked.

And of course if the UI thread is blocking until the task completes at the same time, then you get a deadlock.

> Or does every task go into a locked state?

That's certainly not the case.  It's certainly possible to write tasks that will run to completion without regard for what the UI thread is doing.